# Folder not located inside jar

Tags: java

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][2]
**links-https://www.screencast.com/t/AqbrhIMUbz**

[**Screenshots**][3]

[enter image description here][4]

```
public class UpdateJsonDao {


/** The log. */
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UpdateJsonDao.class);

/** The log 4 j conf path. */
String log4jConfPath = "resources/logg4j.properties";
```

/**
 * Update.
 *
 * @param csv the csv
 * @param json the json
 * @throws Exception the exception
 */
public void update(HashMap csv,HashMap json) throws Exception
{
    //BasicConfigurator.configure();

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
String eid=null;
String user_email=null;
String manager_name=null;


for (int index1 : csv.keySet())          //Fetching each value of Csv 
{
    int count=0;

    String useremail_csv=csv.get(index1).getEmp_email();
    String manager_email=csv.get(index1).getManager_email();

    for(int index2:json.keySet())         //Fetching each value of Json
    {
        for(Bean x:json.get(index2))       
        {    
            String useremail_json=x.getProfile().getF015();
            String oldmanager_email=x.getProfile().getF034();


            if(useremail_json.equals(useremail_csv))       //If user email from Json and Csv are same
            {  

                if(manager_email.equals(oldmanager_email))    //If manaager email id is from Csv and Json are same no need to update(old and new manager email are same)
                {

                    log.info("Manager email already exists"+useremail_csv);
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
                user_email=useremail_json;                   //If manager id is different Update the user 
                eid=x.getID();
                manager_name=csv.get(index1).getManager_name();
                Update(eid,manager_name,manager_email,oldmanager_email,user_email);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
            if(count==0){                                     //If user email is not present in Company database 
        log.warn("Failed Updating Record-->"+useremail_csv);

    }`
```

> enter code here

`I want  to create a jar file of my project.So i kept logg.properties file inside resources folder.When I created a jar a ran it was not able to find resources folder.It was running when I  ran the jar inside the workspace it was running file.I even added resources folder as SourceFolder but still not running.

Comment: it would be helpful to know HOW you are creating the JAR... probably you missed to check some option to include the resource(s)

Comment: Its not a jar file in Resources folder.It is properties file logg4j <b>https://www.screencast.com/t/1SQ4FnBGlz</b>

Comment: I understood that, never wrote about a jar file in the resource folder. You are creating a JAR file and there is a folder (and file) missing in it  so it is very probably that the error is HOW you are creating the JAR file, but we don't know how you are doing it since it was not described in the question. Please add to the question **how you are creating the JAR file?** (not the missing file, the resulting jar file!)

Comment: Steps by which I am creating jar in Eclipse:Export->Runnable jar->Library Handling->Packages required libraries into generated jar and finish